# How to integrate apache and google site via proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, google-sites

My question is "How to integrate apache and google site via proxy"? 
I found this tutorial but it didn't work as I expected. It redirect to google site instead of keep my domain in address bar and change content only.

In my case, I want whenever people access to http://mydomain.com, they will see the content from https://sites.google.com/site/mydomain/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible because you can't acces on the dataBase on your Google Sites. The url of your Google can't change.

Comment: I found this tutorial. But I still can't make it work. http://kenpuca.blogspot.com/2010/09/integrating-apache-and-google-site-via.html